# How do frameworks infleunce application's arcitecture?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, frameworks

I have read in "Design Patterns" book for the gang of four that the framework influences the overall architecture of the Application. Now I know for example when using .NET that you need to inherit from `System.Windows.Form` to make a form (*Although I think I am having a big misconception here*). But can anyone describe in code using any framework how does the framework affect the application architecture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some interesting notes about the topic in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_framework#cite_note-9):

> Software frameworks consist of frozen spots and hot spots. Frozen
>   spots define the overall architecture of a software system (...).
>   These remain unchanged (frozen) in any instantiation of the
>   application framework. Hot spots represent those parts where the
>   programmers using the framework add their own code (...).

According to that, your application can be defined by the Frameworks you're using. For example, in the Java World using Struts frameworks implies that you're using an [MVC architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93View%E2%80%93Controller), or using Spring Framework forces you to apply the [Dependency Injection Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection). If Software Architecture is defined by software patterns, then some frameworks are pre-built patterns for you to utilize.

On the other side, no Software Application is made only by Patterns/Frameworks, an there's were the Hot Spots are usefull: they're ways that Software Frameworks offer to extends/use the frameworks capabilities and build an application according to your requirements and domain.

For example, let's say you're building a Web Application using [Spring MVC Framework](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/mvc.html). After you configure the Framework in your project, every request for your application will be delegated to a class called `DispatcherServlet`. This class is built-in in the Framework and you shouldn't modify it, so it's a perfect example of a **Frozen Spot**. The `DispatcherServlet` will look-up your project configuration and delegate request processing to a `Controller`. The `Controller` is typically a class made by the programmer and has the responsability to process the request. So your hand-made controller it's a **Hot Spot** for you to extend the Framework.

And the DispatcherServlet is an Implementation of the [Front-Controlller Patttern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern), and the Controller usage is typicall of an MVC application; so your application is highly defined by the framework you're using.

Comment: I am more interested in how the frozen spot may confine you.

Comment: I added an example to made it more clear

Answer (score 1):

I must say that a clean Architecture(also Design Patterns) does not depend on which frameworks, toolkits or library are being used. An architecture describes the high level structure of a software system(layers and tiers), not in details how it is implemented. it's a set of principles that help us to achieve some specific goals such as security, usability, extensibility, reliability, maintainability, availability... Let's see a simple example:

Model–view–controller (MVC) is a software architecture(or design pattern) that separates the modeling of the domain, the presentation, and the actions based on user input into three separate classes. The central idea behind MVC is code reusability and separation of concerns. You can apply MVC using many programming languages or frameworks like ASP.Net MVC, Java Strut, PHP DRY, CAKEPHP....

Comment: Say you have designed a framework, in which ways may your framework affect how the your framework's users will build their applications? ASP.NET MVC forces you to follow MVC pattern, but this doesn't mean you cannot apply MVC in ASP.NET, right?

Answer (score 0):

There are different approaches in ways of passing, storing or evaluating data in different frameworks. IF you're working with a Windows Form application, you can reach your view elements from anywhere of the project, since they are all in the computer's local memory and nowhere else.

However, if you're working with an ASP.NET application, there are different sides consuming the project, client and server and things get more complex. The design you're making has almost nothing common with Forms.

If you're working with an ASP.NET MVC application, there are three tiers: ModelViewController, and operations are divided into these and from now on, you need to do your design in a way that fits with these tiers. You have database table-object relations provided by MVC which could change the design totally.

Also programming language lying beneath the program changes the design, as it can be functional, object-oriented etc.

In short, this is not a constructive question. You'll figure out this questions answer after working with different programming languages and technologies.

Comment: As I explained in the question, I want to know how do the framework influences the application, I am sure there is a deep side to it and that is what I want to know. I do not expect Eric Gamma to throw such words carelessly. I think you misinterpreted my question sir but thank you anyway.